# why page scroll to top after toggle menu

Tags: jquery, css

My menu has a fixed class, after the button is clicked the container is display as none, and menu shows, but when clicking it again for a toggle effect, the page scroll to the top, I want it to apear at the same place the button has been clicked.
As the menumobileactive class covers all the page, I used an absolute class to change his property of letting it to scroll, but again when the container is shown again, it apears at the top of the page.
How could the container apear at the same place where the button has been cliked

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("menu-on");
    $(".menumobileactive").toggleClass("visible");
    $(".menu").toggleClass("absolute");
    $(".container").toggleClass("invisible");
});

<div class="menu">
    <div class="menumobile">
        <button>
            <span class="line line-t"></span>
            <span class="line line-m"></span>
            <span class="line line-b"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="menudesktop">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the page uploded casarossa.com.mx , try to toggle the button on the mobile version, why when is clicked at the end of the page, it resets the container at the begining???

Comment: Do you mind providing a bit more code, a working example of what you are describing.

Comment: Yes when i click on my button, container is displayed none, but when is clicked again it shows but it displays the div at the top of it. For example if a user clicks the button at the middle of the container i want that it apears again at ht emiddle not at the top of the div

Comment: Can you make your code into a stack snippet with the HTML included?

Comment: Theres the html

Comment: Menu desktop is converted into menumobile for mobile and menumobileactive are the links at mobile

Comment: Here is the page uploded http://casarossa.com.mx/ , try to toggle the button on the mobile version, why when is clicked at the end of the page, it resets the container at the begining???

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("button").on("click",function(e){

    //prevents from scrolling to top behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).toggleClass("menu-on");
    $(".menumobileactive").toggleClass("visible");
    $(".menu").toggleClass("absolute");
    $(".container").toggleClass("invisible");
});
```

Comment: this didint work, thank you for the support, i want that the container div, apears again at the position that the usser left it, for example as my page has images, i want that if the user toggles the button the container has the position, or image that the user has clicked the button, and not apear at the top

Comment: If you only toogle the class that causes the display: none; I dont get why the position should change.

Comment: Try it with the one line, that causes the appearance and disappearance only.

    $(".menu").toggleClass("absolute");
by the name I could imagine this line is the bad boy

Comment: I use that class to let the position fixed div to scroll, for when the screen is not large enpugh to show all my links, but still when i clicked again the button to display the container it apears at the top, and not where it was left

Comment: I already delited that line, and still apears at the top of the div

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of this particular line:
`$(".contenido").toggleClass("hide");`

Basically, you don't really need to hide the content, since you're in mobile view, just show the new mobile menu (when open) full screen and hide it when button was clicked again.
Because you are hiding and bringing the main content back it automatically scrolls to the top. Why? I can't really explain because I don't have knowledge of how jQuery works this out really hehe but removing that line would fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this with a search and it solved my problem.
When clicked the page would scroll to the top, which was not wanted. With preventDefault() this does not happen anymore. Thank you very much :-)

This here works:

```
 jQuery( ".link_to_click" ).on( "click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery( "#opening_closing_element" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
      });
    });
```